# Excel not auto-filling correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, auto-form-fill

I have an excel document with formulas in it that are referencing items the same space away.  For example:

```
=C9/C10
=P9/P10
=AC9/AC10
=AP9/AP10
=BC9/BC10
=BP9/BP10
```

But excel isn't picking up on this pattern.  Any ideas on how excel can recognize this?

Comment: Are you dragging down or accross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dragging down use:

```
=INDEX($9:$9,,(ROW(1:1)-1)*13+3)/INDEX($10:$10,,(ROW(1:1)-1)*13+3)
```

If you are dragging accross:

```
=INDEX($9:$9,,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*13+3)/INDEX($10:$10,,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*13+3)
```

This just does simple math to return the correct column number to the INDEX.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the dynamic R1C1 reference everywhere (i.e. if you did Copy Paste Formula it would work successfully) it might make more sense to make [a named range](https://exceljet.net/named-ranges) that is actually a calculation and does this for you. Here's how to accomplish:

- Click on a cell you want this calculation to happen (cell d3 in my example)
- Click on the tab FORMULAS
- Click on `Name Manager`
- Click on New Name
- Click on the cells you would use to make the calculation (this is where you would normally specifiy a named range)
- Make sure to take out the $ signs (this might require some surgical clicking as using key arrows will create more references).
- Name it and click `OK`.
- Now whenever you insert that calculation, just type `=yourNamedRang` and it will execute the calculation as if you had pasted copyPaste Formula into that cell.

[image: See Example]

**Final result:**

[image: illustration]